# Customer getUpdateAt() doens't return correct datetime?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, customer

I tried to get customer `update_at` datetime string in Magento 2, but unfortunately it doesn't return correct datetime as it supposed to be.

Here is what I get after dumped `\Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer` object

```
array (size=28)
  'id' => int 3
  'group_id' => int 1
  'default_billing' => string '2' (length=1)
  'default_shipping' => string '2' (length=1)
  'confirmation' => null
  'created_at' => string '2016-04-13 07:28:54' (length=19) [UCT]
  'updated_at' => string '2016-04-19 04:40:05' (length=19) [UCT]
```

But inside `customer_entity` table, it is showing different datetime

```
2016-04-13 14:28:54 (locale, store time)
2016-04-19 11:50:37 (locale, store time)
```

Anybody have any idea about this situation?

Comment: Which the timezone you are using?

Comment: @Neodan : Indochina Timezone (Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot, that Magento is adapting the time output by your timezone (which is selected in the Magento store configuration).

Comment: It is not true, I tried multiple of timezone in store configurations. It always using UTC timezone when you dump an object by `getData()`

Comment: Everything is working as was designed. The time is always stored in the UTC time zone and only the output is adopted by the user time zone. I do not understand where you are seeing the problem.

Comment: Basically, I need to get customer update time via `getUpdatedAt()`. The time displayed is in UTC timezone. So I need to format it to my store timezone? Do you know how?